# execlp with find as parameter

Tags: c, linux, find, exec

I'll try to explain my problem. If i execute the following command

```
find ~ -name file.txt
```

in Linux, all the files that are named `file.txt` will be displayed on the console screen. I want to make a C program that will do the same thing, using the `execlp` function to find all files that have a certain name like `file.txt`.

If I do something like this:

```
execlp("find","find","-name","file.txt",NULL);
```

it compiles fine , but at execution it only displays the file with the name `file.txt` that is located in current working directory. 
If i do something like this in my program:

```
execlp("find","find","~","-name","file.txt");
```

it compiles fine,but at execution it gives me the following error:

```
find: `~': No such file or directory.
```

What parameters should i give to the `execlp` function to search for `file.txt` in all available directories? I need to do this with the `execlp` function.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Your shell is expanding `~` from the cmd-line, but not in the `execlp` invoke. Use a full path or specify a directory element that actually exists (`.` leaps to mind).

Comment: The thing is this program should work for different user accounts. For example, if my friend is running this program on his account , he should get all the files with the name "file.txt" that exist in his filesystem.A user doesn't have acces rights to other user's files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "~" in your first example is expanded by the shell, not the kernel. When executing a command in C, you don't go through the shell, so you can't expect that kind of substitution to happen for you. Well, unless you do actually invoke a shell and ask it to run your command, as in `execlp("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "find", "~", ...);`.

The prefered way to perform what you are doing would be to check the HOME environment variable, or to obtain the home directory for the current user from the password database. Here is how to do it.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *homedir = getenv("HOME");
if (homedir == NULL) {
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    homedir = pw->pw_dir;
}
```

Then simply replace the "~" argument in your code  by the homedir variable.

Comment: Thanks man, this works just fine. And thank you everybody for your help.

Comment: I updated my code to first check the HOME environment variable, as per getpwuid's man page recommendation. This is what the "~" in bash would do. This is done so to allow a user to redefine his own home directory. Note however that relying on the HOME environemnt variable might be innapropriate if you need an authoritative answer (that is, if allowing the user to alter his home directory might lead to security issue.